# Numbers after the comma do not appear when using formattable() in R

Tags: r, formattable

I'm using the formattable package to generate the table view of my data.frame. However I noticed that some columns do not show the numbers after the comma (decimal).

For example: the columns "v", "p" and "t" the formattable omitted the characters after the comma (decimal). Why does this happen?

```
aa2<-read.table(text="Ano   v   u   a   p   ur  h   e   t
2005    1782135.22  113711.81   98964.84    2207446.25  3876.68 7085.74 3265.89 59030602.87
2006    1719687.83  167937.4    97068.3 2218090.61  3936.55 6811.86 2952.21 59030602.87
2007    1755637.78  122799.6    94299.72    2229590.5   3978.23 6858.66 3171.66 59030602.87
2008    1779051.85  97385.73    101739.73   2225127.88  3996.84 6929.01 2254.58 59030602.87
2009    1805123.7   74061.79    109175.68   2215819.96  4126.57 6771.5  1406.21 59030602.87
2010    1716896.85  168013.92   108014.05   2210652.42  4210.9  7162.69 1535.68 59030602.87
2011    1736892.8   151980.31   113991.8    2200158.22  4259.77 7759.18 1442.06 59030602.87
2012    1757330.63  133273.24   125825.1    2185550.21  4419.45 8129.58 1958.48 59030602.87
2013    1639912.63  248584.77   140183.71   2171799.74  4531.06 8687.48 2777.32 59030602.87
2014    1657021.54  227375.14   180036.19   2136407.51  4631.85 8724.39 2287.94 59030602.87
2015    1720644.41  151089.44   190536.46   2138270.92  4733.71 8911.75 2298.34 59030602.87
2016    1662281.39  202916.33   210776.21   2124964.42  4803.06 8575.97 2165.52 59030602.87
2017    1716427.7   136156.44   230587.13   2117936.68  4809.71 8386.94 2170.25 59030602.87
2018    1638715.79  204483.2    255703.3    2101912.82  4931.96 8366.64 2349.4  59030602.87
", sep="", header = TRUE)

aa2

#Formatar a tabela
formattable(aa2, list(
  'v' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'u' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'a' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'p' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'ur' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'h' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'e'= color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc")
  ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have rounded.  We could avoid by applying `comma` to create a `formattable` attribute on top of the `numeric` columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
aa2 <- aa2  %>%
   mutate(across(v:t, ~ formattable::comma(., digits = 2, big.mark = "")))

formattable::formattable(aa2, list(
  'v' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'u' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'a' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'p' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'ur' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'h' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'e'= color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc")
))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: @wesleysc352 I didn't get your question.  I was just updating the original object `aa2` by modifying the columns

Comment: EDIT: the code it worked, but why `aa2` in `aa2 <- aa2 %>%` be repeated?

Comment: @wesleysc352 lets say if you do `aa2 %>%  mutate(across(v:t, ~ formattable::comma(., digits = 2, big.mark = "")))` without assignment `<-`, it will just print the output to the console and does not change the original object.  That is the reason I assigned it back to that object.  You can say the the r-value is the data (rhs of `<-`) and l-value is the address or object

Answer (score 1):

This setting is controlled by `options` which decides number of digits to be displayed. If you set `n` in `options(digits = n)` to a high number, all the numbers would be visible by default.

```
library(formattable)

options(digits = 10)

formattable(aa2, list(
  'v' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'u' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'a' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'p' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'ur' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'h' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'e'= color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc")
))
```

[image]

The default value is 7 which does not allow all digits to be displayed. If you reduce the number further you'll see it's effect on other columns as well.

```
options(digits = 4)

formattable(aa2, list(
  'v' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'u' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'a' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'p' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'ur' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'h' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'e'= color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc")
))
```

[image]